# How to cache whole webpage in ios 4 and above

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, ios4, http-caching

I am new to iphone development. I would like to know how to do the caching in ios 4 and above??
I got many answers but right now I get confused and don't know from where to start.

In my project, I am doing http request and displaying results using `UIWebView`

Here,I want to cache the http data. So next time when application starts again then It will reload the data from the cache.

how to cache the webpage data in IOs 4 and above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done with caching of whole web page using ASIHTTPRequest. [I go through the ASIHTTPRequest: here is a link to it.](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to make use of Core Data to store your data locally by modeling your data in it. You will need to go through the core data programming guide: here is a link to it.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CoreData.pdf

After you have understood for how to store your data, you will able to easily able to load this when your app starts the next time.
Im not sure of how to store the web view's data as an html page locally, though that can be an alternative approach too.
I hope it helps you!!! Cheers!!

Comment: You don't really need to use Core Data for this, you could use local file system.